# How to stop GCC from optimising assertions away

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, gcov

I already have -O0

I run unit tests (similar idea to cunit) on my code. The code is built with IAR's EWARM, but I use GCC (version 4.5.4, mingw-w64/oz) with gcov to verify my unit tests' coverage.

(Why such an old version? I had problems getting a mingw that didn't crash on Windows 7; when I got one, I stayed with it.)

Here's an extract from GCOV's output:

```
    2:  926:Boolean PtpTimeZero(const TPtpTime *t)
    6:  927:{
    -:  928:  Boolean result;
    -:  929:
#####:  930:  assert(t != NULL);
    2:  931:  assert(t->nanoseconds > -ONENANO);
    2:  932:  assert(t->nanoseconds <  ONENANO);
    -:  933:
    2:  934:  result = (t->seconds == 0U) && (t->nanoseconds == 0);
    2:  935:  return result;
    -:  936:}
```

GCOV does not see line 930 getting executed, so my unit test coverage does not hit 100%, which is not good. The lines before and after get run, so I think line 930 is getting optimised out.

I have tried to find how to turn off all optimisations, but this happens even with optimisations set to 0.

How can I make GCC run all the lines in my program?

Comment: I can't find anything to prove this should make any difference, but did you try using the -g flag?

Comment: Yes, I always have -g because I think it is needed for GCOV to work. (I could be wrong about that, but either way I do have -g)

Comment: Coverage is not always super reliable. How do you interpret the '6' at the beginning of the second line? I would check the asm if you have a doubt.